# How to get job status in Node.js Agenda?

Tags: node.js, agenda

[agendash](https://github.com/agenda/agendash) is an extension of [Agenda](https://github.com/agenda/agenda). This package can list which schedules are currently running. There is a `status` field, because I want to make another panel, how do I get this `status` through the `Agenda`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

cron job should be executed in "job Repeated Field" and try to keep it simple, use cron guru for help instead of using this pattern:

```
0/3 9,10,11,12,14,15,16,17 * * 1-6
```

use this pattern:

[image]